# How to remove content inside a div tag using gsub in R

Tags: r, gsub

how can i remove the content inside a div tags, using gsub knowing the fact that it could contain other div inside which they should be removed.

Given this example

```
"<div id="body-wrapper"><div id="outer"><span>text text</span></div></div>"
```

the gsub function should extract only the div parent

```
<div id="body-wrapper"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`gsub` is probably not the easiest or best way to do this, but could:

```
gsub('>.*$', '></div>', string)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `str_extract_all` function from the `stringr` package to extract your desired text.

```
x1<-'<div id="body-wrapper"><div id="outer"><span>text text</span></div></div>'
y1<-unlist(str_extract_all(x1, '<div id="([^<]*)"><'))
paste0(y1, '/div>', collapse="")
```

Output: `<div id=\"body-wrapper\"></div>`